# Seam FacesContextFactory

Tags: seam, graniteds

I've enabled by graniteds/tide application to use Seam security. As part of the seam setup I register this listener with the webapp

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My application now fails on start up with this error. Do I need to explicitly include a java faces jar with my app. I understood that Jboss prefers to use its own.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at org.granite.seam.SeamInterceptor.initializeFacesContext(SeamInterceptor.java:292)
    at org.granite.seam.SeamInterceptor.before(SeamInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3MessageProcessor.process(AMF3MessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF0MessageProcessor.process(AMF0MessageProcessor.java:78)
    at org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFMessageServlet.doPost(AMFMessageServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.arantech.cw.pa.webapp.NoCachingFilter.doFilter(NoCachingFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFMessageFilter.doFilter(AMFMessageFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:725)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239)
    at org.granite.seam.SeamInterceptor.initializeFacesContext(SeamInterceptor.java:280)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the old exceptions I already saw months ago. I can't directly help you. I dismissed Seam3 back then because it cost a lot of time to get things up and running and in some servers like Tomcat it had (maybe still has) a lot of issues. If you think about it, it isn't surprising. Seam3 is a complete new implementation and some colleagues already call it Seam 0.3 because it used to be that unstable. We switched to a different [portable extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973364/is-cdi-a-good-replacement-of-spring/7140655#7140655) which is way more stable and provides more innovations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems like you need to have a faces jar at "/usr/jboss/server/default/lib" location.